# Facebook PHP-SDK find friends with more likes but only in certain app_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I want to extract from facebook php-sdk a list of my friends who "Liked" certain posts which are only from certain app_id. Let me give you an example, if you go to www.rottentomatoes.com you can see in Friends / Friends section all your friends that wrote a review/critic on whatever film.

I thought FQL was a nice and clean way to do this, but actually it is not, as it's taking too long processing the data I dont think it could be ready for an online app yet.

This was the code that I came up with so far:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a["like"] == $b["like"]) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a["like"] > $b["like"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

    try
    {
        $fql = 'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1='.$uid.') AND has_added_app = 1';
        $_friends = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $fql));
    }
    catch(FacebookApiException $e)
    {
        print_r($e);
        error_log($e->getType());

    }

    // Extract the user ID's returned in the FQL request into a new array.
    $likes = array();
    if (is_array($_friends) && count($_friends) > 0)
    {   
        foreach ($_friends as $friend)
        {
            $fid = $friend["uid"];

            try
            {
                $fql = 'SELECT url FROM url_like WHERE user_id = '.$fid.' AND strpos(lower(url),"muchogusto") >=0';
                $_likes = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' => $fql));
                $likes[] = array("uid" => $fid, "like" => count($_likes));
            }
            catch(FacebookApiException $e)
            {
                $likes[] = array("uid" => $fid, "like" => 0);
                continue;
                error_log($e->getType());
            }
        }   
    }

    usort($likes, "cmp");
    print_r($likes);
```

I have plenty of questions, and sure you can help me with this as I'm pretty newbie.

Can someone kindly help me coding this without FQL? I only need this:

1. List of my FRIENDS
2. Number of LIKES of certain posts that are only on
3. certain APP_ID

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FQL isn't the problem. It's the fact that you're making FQL calls in a `foreach` loop. That's what is slowing your program down.

If you're calling this function within another `foreach` loop, then forget about it.

Try making one call with a FQL multiquery.

```
$queries['my_friends'] = 
  'SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) 
   AND has_added_app = 1';
$queries['liked_url'] = 
  'SELECT url,user_id FROM url_like WHERE user_id IN (SELECT uid FROM #my_friends) 
   AND strpos(lower(url),"muchogusto") >=0';
$multiquery = json_encode($queries);
$result = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.multiquery','queries' => $multiquery));
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response cpilko. Is it possible instead of relying in strpos, search the posts by app_id? I think it could be faster than a text search by URL address, is that possible in FQL as the FQL is taking too long to proccess this query: 10 seconds!! which is too much. Do you think there could be any other way to do the same query in Open Graph and forget FQL???

Comment: Graph API does not have any filtering built in. The only way you can filter a query on Facebook's side is with FQL. I'm not sure if there is a way to optimize this further.

Comment: I wonder how the guys from www.rottentomatoes.com do this exact development to load that fast...

Comment: If you're comparing your site to a large site, don't. They may have a cross-marketing deal with Facebook, and may have access to a completely different set of tools than us mere mortals do.